# Codeigniter 3 encryptacion de URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy usando codeigniter 3 y su librería de encriptación para ocultar los parámetros que van en la url, de momento tengo esto.

```
<?php
$text = 5;
$encryptext = $this->encryption->encrypt($text);   
?>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('test_controller/recibe/'.$encryptext);?>" class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Enviar</a>
```

para efectos de prueba doy un valor fijo el cual envió en la url encriptado, el cual lo envió a un controlador ahí aplico la desencriptacion, el valor lo utilizo para realizar una consulta en la base de datos y los resultados los envió a otra vista.

```
 $data['codigo'] = $this->encryption->decrypt($codigo);
 $data['documentos'] = $this->propuestas_model->get_detalle_test($data);
 $this->load->view('test/recibe',$data);
```

En algunos casos la información llega bien a la vista, un array con todo el contenido, para otros casos recibo bool(false) array(0) { }.

Comment: Tendrías que asegurarte que `$encryptext` este correctamente codificado para ser enviado por URL. Intenta imprimirlo usando [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php)